# NuGet referencing to older DLLs upon installation

Tags: c#, nuget

I have a .NET 4.5 project and I'm installing a library with lots of dependencies (for example this: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries/0.9.6-preview)

Many of those dependencies have net40 and net45 binaries in separate folders of package. However as you can see below they are referenced to net40 and net35 ones even though there was a net45 version available in the package. (it referenced to some net45 ones as well)

What could cause this?

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Data.Edm">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\external\Nuget\Microsoft.Data.Edm.5.6.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Data.OData">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\external\Nuget\Microsoft.Data.OData.5.6.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Data.OData.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\external\Nuget\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common.0.9.8-preview\lib\net45\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common.NetFramework">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\external\Nuget\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common.0.9.8-preview\lib\net45\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common.NetFramework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\external\Nuget\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager.1.8.0.0\lib\net35-full\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management, Version=0.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\external\Nuget\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.0.9.5-preview\lib\net40\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\external\Nuget\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute.0.9.9-preview\lib\net40\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\external\Nuget\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.0.9.2-preview\lib\net40\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Scheduler">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\external\Nuget\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Scheduler.0.9.8-preview\lib\net40\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Scheduler.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.ServiceBus">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\external\Nuget\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.ServiceBus.0.9.3-preview\lib\net40\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.ServiceBus.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\external\Nuget\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql.0.9.4-preview\lib\net40\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Storage">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\external\Nuget\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Storage.0.9.3-preview\lib\net40\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Storage.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.VirtualNetworks">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\external\Nuget\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.VirtualNetworks.0.9.3-preview\lib\net40\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.VirtualNetworks.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\external\Nuget\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites.0.9.3-preview\lib\net40\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\external\Nuget\WindowsAzure.Storage.3.0.3.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll</HintPath>
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check that your project is really a .NET 4.5 project. You could try uninstalling and reinstalling the packages to fix them. Or do what I do and modify the csproj.

Comment: It is .NET 4.5 project. I installed several times on different project. It always does this. I don't know why this happens but apparently I need to modify manually.